# How can I edit SYSTEM_POWER_POLICY in Windows 10 registry?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, power-management

My goal is to edit Windows 10 registry so that Windows 10 ignores CPU usage when it determines whether the system is 'idle'.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-idle-conditions

The above document describes that the CPU idle threshold is 80% in Windows 8, and I think the same applies to Windows 10. I would like to change this and it may be done by editing registry.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-system_power_policy

I found the above document on the web. Some items in this document can be edited on PowerOptions (such as lidClose behavior, etc) of Windows setting, but the others such as "idleSensitivity" cannot be edited in Power Options and I think it may be edited in the Windows Registry.

First, I wonder whether this can be edited in Windows registry.
Second, if the first is true, where is the related items?
I browsed items in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT and others but failed to find it.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: I agree with Ramhound. Currently the question reads as: I have a car. How can I watch television?

Comment: Easier (and safer!) than editing: use Power Options to set the parameters, then export the Registry key.

Comment: @LPChip If I knew where the television is installed in my car, I would have not asked this question.

Comment: @user67275 the point is, I know a fair deal about the registry, but I don't understand what a programming question has to do with the registry. As in... your question is unclear to most of us, and that will cause the question to be closed for being unclear. If you edit the question and explain what the link is and how it all fits together, I can use my knowledge to actually help you.

Comment: @LPChip I appreciate your comments and edited my question. I hope this helps clarifying my point.

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question. I hope it helps to clarify my question. I don't know how to mention DrMoishe Pippik with the nickname including a space..

Comment: Every single user that submitted a comment has been notified of every single comment you submitted since they commented

Comment: what you want to accomplish should be possible using `powercfg.exe /query` and `powercfg /change` (or directly from Control panel -> Power Management, advanced settings)

Comment: Also, try setting your Power Plan to High Performance (if you don't have that one, create a new one based on the template High Performance) with the name High Performance. It may already do what you want to do.

Comment: The power settings in registry editor should be under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power. But I am not sure how to edit idleSensitivity or if this can be edited.